# Increase the docker container volume in AWS batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

I have pushed a docker image to AWS Batch. While Im trying to execute a job using the Batch, the entire default container space of 10GB is getting used up. Is there a way to increase the default container space without creating a new AMI instance?

Comment: Got it from https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/increase-default-ecs-docker-limit/